# Is a cheerleading captain equal to a cheer leader?

Tags: word-usage

Is a cheerleading captain equal to a cheer leader?

I know that a cheerleader means a member of cheerleading squad, and a cheerleading captain means the leader of the team. I am wondering if we can use "cheer leader" separately to mean the captain.

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that those terms are equivalent?

Answer (score 3):

I would probably not say a "cheer leader", because most people would find it confusing and assume you would mean a cheerleader. If you wanted to say a "cheerleader leader" that might be more acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

No, being the captain of a cheerleading squad isn't the same as just being the leader of the cheers.

The captain is a member of the team who has leadership duties on top of their work as a member of the team. These include scheduling practices, maintaining team morale, liaising with school authorities, selecting and choreographing the cheers, etc.

While the captain of a cheerleading team often leads the cheers, they don't necessarily do that job. Any member of the team could lead, or the coach could be leading from the sidelines.